# Nexus 7 tablet not displaying on "Android Device Chooser" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nexus-7

I already set the manifest to debug, enabled the decide to development and upgraded the usb driver and it still doesn't show the devices on the "Android Device Chooser" window

Comment: Hi. Try to install driver from Google - http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
It helped for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried obvious solutions and then non-obvious and obvious again

I applied everything I researched, what was missing was running eclipse as Administrator on windows 7

apparently it requires some rights on host os to perform usb debugging

good luck for the next searching this

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled ADB?

`Settings -> Developer Options -> Android debugging`?

Unless ADB is enabled Eclipse wont be able to talk with the device.

Comment: yes, it is, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Android Studio 0.2.2 (IntelliJ). On Windows 7 my Nexus 7 did not appear in device chooser although it was fine on my Mac. I could also browse my Nexus 7 in Windows Explorer.

In the end I needed to install the Asus USB drivers for the Nexus 7 [(link)](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=28&s=2):

After that ADB detected my Nexus and everything worked as expected.